# CakePHP REST Basic Mapping Not Working As Expected

Tags: rest, cakephp, routes, mapping

Followed the Cake Book example almost exactly.

```
Router::mapResources('incidentReports');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Both before

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

My controller called IncidentReportsController

```
class IncidentReportsController extends AppController {
```

Which contains functions

```
index()
view($id)
add()
edit($id)
delete($id)
```

Going to the URL

```
www.myurl.com/incidentReports.json
```

Sends the request to the index() function as expected.

Going to the URL

```
www.myurl.com/incidentReports/260.json
```

Should map to the view() function but trys to map to a 260() function which doesn't exist.

```
www.myurl.com/incidentReports/view/260.json
```

Does map to the view() function and works properly.  However, my understanding is the "view" in the URL shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Did you include the `RequestHandlerComponent` in your App- or IncidentReportsController ?

Comment: Its in there.  But thank you for the idea.

Comment: How did you try the request? with a browser? Already tried it with a rest-client like Postman (A Google Chrome Browser App)? Another problem could be that the RequestHandler only looks at the `Accept` Header in the HTTP Request. There you need a `Accept: application/json` or the `RequestHandler` will treat it as a normal GET Request.

Comment: have you ever solved this? I am having the exact same problem as well from my app as from a RestClient tool.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. In my case I was able to fix it by changing the controller name in the URL.

Didn't work: `http://www.example.com/entityName.json`
Works fine:  `http://www.example.com/entity_name.json`

Comment: Actually, this makes sense. The `mapResources` function does a `Inflector::underscore` to the controller name, so there would be no match between `entityName/:action` and `entity_name/:action`, for example. This happens since version 1.3 (or before, didn't check). [API reference](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Router.html#462-510).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html), you've done everything right, so I'm not sure. Try putting this (the routes that should be enabled) in your routes too.

```
Router::resourceMap(array(
    array('action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false),
    array('action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => false),
    array('action' => 'edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => true),
    array('action' => 'update', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => true)
));
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, just did that right before posting this question. No change.

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is within a plugin, you must specify as well..

e.g:
   Router::mapResources('Plugin.Controller');